# errors when i use subsonic

Tags: c#, subsonic, subsonic3

i downloaded subsonic and am using the instructions in this page 
http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_ActiveRecord. i get the following error when i run the custom tool on ActiveRecord.tt, Context.tt and Structs.tt files. i dont know where to look to troubleshoot.

Error 2 A namespace does not directly contain members such as fields or methods E:\TradingTools\code\TorontoTraderDataVer2\TorontoTraderDataVer2\Context.cs 1 1 TorontoTraderDataVer2

Comment: Are you still getting this error?

Comment: nope. not having the issue anymore